# How to filter a query on specific date format in mongodb?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I am getting `date parameter` in the `string format 'yyyyMMdd'`.

I have a collection in mongodb which has a property `CallDate ISODate()`, i need to write down a query which will filter the date parameter.

In **SQL Server**, we just use the query

```
select * from xyz x with (nolock) 
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), Cast(x.CallDate as datetime), 112)  = @pDateParameter
```

how could i achieve the same filter in **mongodb**

```
db.getCollection("_xyz").find({CallDate : ?}) //How to adjust that filter here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4 version.

Use `$addFields` to add the string formatted date property followed by `$match` on date parameter  and later if you prefer you can drop the string date column by using `$project` with exclusion.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
       { $addFields: {yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y%m%d", date: "$CallDate" } } } },
       { $match: {"yearMonthDay":date parameter}},
       { $project:{"yearMonthDay":0}}
    ])
```

Comment: could you elaborate the usage of $project here?

Comment: Project with exclusion on field is used to remove the extra date string field we added as part of aggregation pipeline. Here is more information. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields